# Efficiently store list into pandas with df.loc

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I am running time tests on some of my slowest code and have isolated a snippet that is taking the longest.

This snippet takes data from a list and stores it into the df. I know for loops are pretty taboo when interacting with pandas so I'm wondering if I can speed this up.

I have a list of all 'issues' that I have no choice but to iterate over with the outer for loop and the use an inner for loop to insert each issue into the df:

```
for issues in all_issues:
    # Some code to get the current key of the issue to use in df.loc to insert in the right place
    # Some code to get and append each issue's data to a list named (to_status)
    for i in range(len(to_status)):
        df.loc[key, ('T' + str(i + 1) + ' - To')] = to_status[i]
```

Doesn't really matter what the list is, I'm using a few different lists in fact. Though they can be of variable length thus the need for `range(len(to_status))`.

If the list is `['Open','Closed','Open']` and the key is `4000` the output would be:

```
df
key    T1 - To    T2 - To    T3 - To 
4000   'Open'     'Closed'   'Open'
```

- Is there a faster way to complete this insert?

Thanks.

Comment: would you like show us some sample data ?

Comment: L = ['Open','Closed','Open']

#create new df 
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':L})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the loop, I can suggest constructing a DataFrame directly from the list of lists. Then manually adjust the column names and index as needed. Something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(all_issues)
df.columns = ['T' + str(c+1) + ' - To' for c in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no sample data, so I'm assuming your dataset is similar to this, Key and values as list.

```
d={
    'key1': [10, 100.1, 0.98, 1.2],
    'key2': [72.5],
    'key3': [1, 5.2, 71.2, 9, 10.11, 12.21, 65, 7]
}

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index').transpose()
```

**Output:**

```
    key3    key2    key1
0   1.00    72.5    10.00
1   5.20    NaN     100.10
2   71.20   NaN     0.98
3   9.00    NaN     1.20
4   10.11   NaN     NaN
```